# Porcentagem de cada valor dentro um campo da tabela. O campo armazena dois valores, 1 para sim e 2 para Não

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Eu estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação de pesquisa de satisfação pra um cliente onde o usuário responde algumas perguntas com números de 1 a 10 e outra de sim ou não.

Em um dos relatórios, mostro a média de cada campo do banco, porém nos campos de pergunta de sim ou não, estou salvando 1 para sim e 2 para não.

Estou com dúvida se é possível resolver só com o banco de dados, retornando apenas a porcentagem de cada resposta do campo.

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id_pesquisa)"pesquisas", 
FORMAT(AVG(p.atendimento),2)"atendimento", 
FORMAT(AVG(p.espera),2)"espera", 
FORMAT(AVG(p.ambiente),2)"ambiente", 
FORMAT(AVG(p.qualidade_produtos),2)"qualidade_produtos", 
FORMAT(AVG((p.atendimento + p.espera + p.ambiente + p.qualidade_produtos)/4),2)'media'
FROM empresa e 
INNER JOIN campanha c ON (e.id_empresa = c.id_empresa)
INNER JOIN pesquisa p ON (c.id_campanha = p.id_campanha)
WHERE c.id_empresa = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo nesse sentido pode resolver o seu problema, mas eu indicaria o uso de uma view no banco para facilitar a busca dos dados desse relatório.

```
SELECT  (SELECT SUM(u.atendimento = 'S') FROM pesquisa u) / (SELECT COUNT(u.id_pesquisa) FROM pesquisa u) AS satisfacaoAtendimento
```

Para ajudar na questão do filtro, você pode usar os dados do select exterior no where do interior, da seguinte forma

```
  SELECT  (SELECT SUM(u.atendimento = 'S') FROM pesquisa u WHERE p.id_pesquisa = u.id_pesquisa) /
    (SELECT COUNT(u.id_pesquisa) FROM pesquisa u  WHERE p.id_pesquisa = u.id_pesquisa) AS satisfacaoAtendimento
FROM empresa e
INNER JOIN campanha c ON (e.id_empresa = c.id_empresa)
INNER JOIN pesquisa p ON (c.id_campanha = p.id_campanha)
WHERE c.id_empresa = 4
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta João, realmente vi a necessidade da criação de uma view ou procedure. Como faz entorno de 3 anos que não trabalho com programação, acabei esquecendo grande parte. 
Tentei criar uma view, mas como o campo ID da tabela pesquisa recebeu um COUNT não consegui filtrar mais pelo ID da empresa. Tem algum conseglho?

Comment: Editei a resposta para tentar deixar ela mais completa e tentar resolver esse seu problema. Caso ainda não tenha respondido a sua pergunta, tente ir postando como o seu código está ficando para facilitar o entendimento do problema.